# How to merge two table with pyfits?

Tags: python, astropy, pyfits

I am using Python 2.7.10 And pyfits 3.3. Earlier, I have used the following code to merge two tables. However, now I am getting some errors

```
t1 = pyfits.open(table1)[1].columns
t2 = pyfits.open(table2)[1].columns
new_columns = t1 + t2
hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(new_columns)
hdu.writeto(outtable)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/vvikraman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfits/hdu/table.py", line 116, in from_columns
    data = FITS_rec.from_columns(coldefs, nrows=nrows, fill=fill)
 File "/home/vvikraman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfits/fitsrec.py", line 315, in from_columns
    if arr.hdu.data is None:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use `astropy` (i.e. `astropy.io.fits`)?

In that case the idiom would be:

```
from astropy.table import Table, hstack
t1 = Table.read(table1)
t2 = Table.read(table2)
new = hstack([t1, t2])
new.write(outtable)
```

In both the `read` and `write` calls, you need to provide `format='fits'` if the table name extension(s) do not imply that it is FITS.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit confusing, and I'm not 100% sure about the cause, but here's my guess:

The result of opening the file itself, `pyfits.open(...)`, isn't assigned to anything, because you immediately access the columns of the second HDU. That gives you a weak reference: essentially, the actual data isn't available anymore, because the file is, in a sense (and possibly real, I haven't checked) closed.
Pyfits does this to save memory.

The confusing part is that, after you've assigned `t1` and `t2`, you can still print their definition, so it seems the actual columns are around. In fact, it's the column definitions that are still around: the actual data can't be retrieved. Hence, when you tried to create a new binary HDU from the combination `t1` and `t2`, where you need the actual data, things fail.

The solution is to make sure you keep a proper reference to the data. There might be multiple ways to do this; this seems to work for me:

```
hdulist1 = pyfits.open(table1)
hdulist2 = pyfits.open(table2)
t1 = hdulist1[1].columns
t2 = hdulist2[1].columns
new_columns = t1 + t2
hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(new_columns)
hdu.writeto(outtable)
# explicitly close the HDUs; might free up memory
hdulist1.close()
hdulist2.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Tom and Evert! Tom, that answer solves my problem. Evert, Earlier I did those steps but did not work.

Comment: That's a good explanation of the problem, thanks.  This has revealed a subtle bug that I think I'll try to post a fix for.  However, Tom Aldcroft's answer to use the higher level Astropy Table interface for table manipulation is the way to go for newer code.

Comment: FWIW there's an issue open for this here: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/4345#issuecomment-180957070